# Rhino Mocks problems with private setter in stub

Tags: rhino-mocks, stub, private-members

**Error:**

> You are trying to set an expectation
>   on a property that was defined to use
>   PropertyBehavior. Instead of writing
>   code such as this: mockObject.Stub(x
>   => x.SomeProperty).Return(42); You can use the property directly to achieve
>   the same result:
>   mockObject.SomeProperty = 42;

```
var x = MockRepository.GenerateStub<MyClass>();
x.Stub(s => s.Items).Return(new List<Item>());

public class MyClass
{
    public virtual IEnumerable<Item> Items
    {
        get {return _items;}
        private set {_items = value;}
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Found the solution. Quit the project so that I could chose a tool that works. E.g Moq

Answer (score 8):

I think using a Mock rather than a stub gets around the problem, but there may be a better way I'm missing.

```
        var x = MockRepository.GenerateMock<MyClass>();
        x.BackToRecord(BackToRecordOptions.PropertyBehavior);
        SetupResult.For(x.Items).Return(new List<Item>());
        x.Replay();
```

Comment: I have the same issue, and using a Mock works for me too. Don't understand this limitation on Stubs.

Answer (score 2):

A cleaner way than would be:

```
var x = MockRepository.GenerateMock<MyClass>();
x.Stub(s => s.Items).Return(new List<Item>());
```

I just don't get why GenerateStub doesn't work.

Comment: can confirm this, I believe it's a bug that it doesn't work with GenerateStub

Answer (score 1):

I received this same message. My issue was that I was trying to stub a non-virtual property on a concrete class.